# Open Source / Commercial Skin Component for GUI in C#/VB.net

Tags: c#

Is there any Open Source or Commercial Skin Component for GUI in C#/VB.net? [Ex. VBSkinner for Old visual basic 6]

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX controls went the way of the dodo.  Any .NET component vendor sells a library that includes support for skinning.  Check out Telerik or DevExpress for example.